# ImportError: cannot import name 'QStringList' in PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, qstring, pyqt5

I am using PyQt5 but can't import QStringList. I know that QStringList used to be in the module QtCore in PyQt4. So I try importing the class using

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QStringList
```

but it shows this error

```
C:\Python34\python.exe C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/FirstProject/Test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/FirstProject/Test.py", line 3, in <module>
from PyQt5.QtCore import QStringList
ImportError: cannot import name 'QStringList'
```

I am using PyCharm and it shows in auto-completion something called QStringListModel. I was following the book "Rapid GUI Development with Python and Qt" by Mark Summerfield. How do I use QStringList, or anything else in PyQt5 that will do the job of QStringList?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In PyQt5, there is no `QString` and hence no need for `QStringList`.

Any Qt API that would normally return a `QString`, will automatically return a Python string instead. Similarly, any Qt APIs that would normally return a `QStringList` will return a Python list containing Python strings. And the opposite also applies: any Qt API that would normally *accept* a `QString` or `QStringList` will accept the Python equivalents instead.

This is the same as the default behaviour when using [PyQt4 with Python 3](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/python_v3.html), or when explicitly [setting the API to version 2](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/incompatible_apis.html) using `sip.setapi`.

For more details, see: [Differences Between PyQt4 and PyQt5](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/pyqt4_differences.html) in the [PyQt5 Reference](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/index.html).

Comment: Thanks. I finally got around with the problem with QStringList in PyQt5. Just replaced QStringList with list, that's it!

Answer (score -2):

As I couldn't find a solution to this problem, I came up with a workaround for my needs. I start my python script from a shell script and use grep to ignore the error message. I hope this helps others. `~/run/r_entry.py 2>&1| grep -v FIFinderSyncExtensionHost`

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question.