# Can't import QStringList from QtCore module in PyQt4

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, pyqt4

So I tried importing class using

```
from PyQt4.Qtcore import QStringList
```

but it shows the error

> Import error: Cannot import name 'QStringList'

Comment: It's not implemented, because it's not really needed for anything. Just use a normal python list of strings wherever the Qt APIs require a `QStringList`.

Comment: [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27757678/importerror-cannot-import-name-qstringlist-in-pyqt5) I asked about PyQt5. Strangely `QStringList` used to be supported by PyQt4 back then, or so I thought at least. The answer in that question also says just to use regular python list.

Comment: It's not exactly said to use a regular Python list instead of QStringList in the [doc](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/python_v3.html#qstringlist) but it points to it. Plus, it's more pythonic.